# CakePHP JSON response with specified http headers

Tags: json, cakephp

I need to implement xsolla payment solution into my cakePHP 2.6 webapp.
By contract my site should communicate via REST with Xsolla.

Xsolla does all the requests to the same url (e.g. http://example.com/rest) and specifies the type of request in the JSON body,
e.g. request from Xsolla:

```
URL: http://example.com/rest
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 78
Authorization: Signature 8189119fb35327cdee7787990df41001c4bd9122
{"data":{"notification_type":"user_validation","user":{"id":"user_id"}}}
```

I should return **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request** with error code if the user id is invalid or **HTTP/1.1 200 OK** if the user id is valid.
`notification_type` could be `user_validation`, `payment` and so on.
I implemented all the communication in XsollaController.php in a single function xsolla:

```php
//XsollaController.php:
public function xsolla() {
    //...
    $data = $this->request->data;
    if(array_key_exists("notification_type", $data) &&
            $data["notification_type"]=="user_validation") {
        //user_validation
    }
    else if(array_key_exists("notification_type", $data) &&
            $data["notification_type"]=="payment") {
        //payment
    }
    //...
}
```

How can I have different functions based on `notification_type`?
e.g. function `userValidation($data)`, `payment($data)` etc.

Also what the proper way to return simple JSON with specified HTTP code?
Now I do the following:

```php
if(userIdIsValid($userID)) {
    $body = array('data' => array('user' => array(
        "id"=>$data["user"]["id"]), 'message' => 'USER_IS_VALID'));
    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->response->statusCode(200);
    $this->response->body(json_encode($body));
    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
    exit();
}
else {
    $body = array('error' => array(
        'code' => 'INVALID_USER', 
        'message' => 'INVALID_USER', 
        'user' => array("id"=>$data["user"]["id"])));
    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->response->statusCode(400);
    $this->response->body(json_encode($body));
    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
    exit();
}
```

My code works but seems hard coded. I believe CakePHP provide a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question of executing different functions based on the `notification_type`, you are almost there (unless I am oversimplifying your question).

```
//XsollaController.php:
public function xsolla() {
    //...
    $data = $this->request->data;
    if(array_key_exists("notification_type", $data) &&
            $data["notification_type"]=="user_validation") {
        $this->userValidation($data);
    }
    else if(array_key_exists("notification_type", $data) &&
            $data["notification_type"]=="payment") {
        $this->payment($data);
    }
    //...
}

private function userValidation($data) {
    // user validation
}

private function payment($data) {
    // payment
}
```

As far as responding with JSON content and the correct HTTP status code, your code looks fine.  There's room for some minor improvements, but if it's functional, I'd leave it.  You are setting the response code correctly.  If you want the truly "cake" way of responding with JSON content, read up on [JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) in the CakePHP docs.

Comment: Thanks @mittmemo, I thought about separate actions for every `notification_type` request.  
Don't you think that `invokeAction()` in the `beforeFilter()` function is better approach?